# How can I create a pair of immutable Scala instances that have references to each other?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a simple class that represents a kind of relationship in a simple graph. Relationships are bidirectional and invertable, so if A is "above" B then B must be "below" A.

Supposing I had two instances of Relationship A (Above), and B (Below), that A.invert == B and B.invert == A. To make matters easy, I'd build both A and B from the same factory at the same time.

This is my code so far, obviously wrong:

```
case class Relationship(name:String, inverse:Relationship=null) {
  def setInverse(inverse:Relationship) = {
    Relationship(name, inverse)
  }
}

val foo = Relationship(name="Foo", Relationship(name="Bar"))
printf(foo.toString) // looks fine
printf(foo.inverse.toString) // null
foo.inverse.inverse = foo // totally wrong!!!
```

The last line is obviously invalid because it's attempting to mutate something immutable. I saw an approach that might work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534128/immutable-instances-that-reference-one-another), but not with case-classes? Do I have to abandon case classes if I want to make a circular reference?

How can I make two instances of Relationship, each with a property called inverse which is a reference to the other?

Edit 0: Here's my try #2 - not much better

```
class Relationship(name:String, _inverse:Relationship) {
  lazy val inverse = _inverse
}

val foo:Relationship = new Relationship(name="Foo", new Relationship(name="Bar", foo))
printf(foo.toString)
printf(foo.inverse.toString)
```

When I try this in a scala worksheet I get a java.lang.StackOverflowError, most probably because the sequence foo.inverse.inverse.inverse goes on forever. I've no way of knowing whether I actually constructed an object without preventing this infinite recursion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiating immutable paired objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507965/instantiating-immutable-paired-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that you can't do that with a case class because of the fields of the case class that are inevitably like `val`s.

One solution using a class would be to define `Relationship` as follows:

```
class Relationship(name:String, _inverse: =>Relationship) {
  lazy val inverse = _inverse  //it could be defined as def as well
}                              //but good call on lazy evaluation
```

the only difference with your previous definition is that _inverse is "call-by-name", that is `_inverse` won't be evaluated until we really need to evaluate it to get a value out of it.

then you can do crazy stuff like:

```
scala> val a: Relationship = new Relationship("foo", new Relationship("bar", a))
a: Relationship = Relationship@695aa1

scala> a.inverse.inverse
res3: Relationship = Relationship@695aa1
```

or even

```
 scala> val a: Relationship = new Relationship("foo", a)
    a: Relationship = Relationship@14471f25
scala> a.inverse
res6: Relationship = Relationship@14471f25
```

**EDIT for first question below**: The magic appears because we have at the same time a `lazy val` field of the class Relationship, **and** because a parameter of the constructor of `Relationship` is `call-by-name`.
A `call-by-name` parameter is reevaluated every time(like would be a def) it is called in the body of the structure it is the parameter. Now that's good because if you put it on the right side of an equality with a `lazy val`, the `lazy val` won't "call" anything on its right hand side until the `lazy val` is itself called. So you're saying to inverse: 
alright `inverse`, you will have to call `_inverse` later in the future to get its value but not now, and thus **at creation** of a Relationship since in the body of `Relationship` you're telling to evaluate nowhere `_inverse` until you call `inverse`, you never have to evaluate `_inverse` until you call `inverse`.

**EDIT 2** for pattern matching:
It appeared to me that you wanted to use pattern matching with your class Relationship, to do so you would have to define a companion object/extractor like this:

```
object Relationship {
  def unapply(r: Relationship): Option[(String, Relationship)] = 
         Some((r.name, r.inverse))
}
```

also you'd have to assign a `val`, `lazy val` or `def` that references the `name` parameter you give to `Relationship` to be able to access it from outside by defining Relationship like so for example:

```
class Relationship(val name: String, ...//next part same as before
```

then you could do nice pattern matching like so:

```
    scala>val a: Relationship = 
             new Relationship("foo", new Relationship("bar", a))
    a: Relationship = Relationship@31f44709

scala>a match {
     |   case Relationship("bar", aPrim) if aPrim eq a => 
                       "this is not the case here"
     |   case Relationship("foo", Relationship("bar", aPrim)) if aPrim eq a =>
                       "this is the truth"
     |   case _ => "wat"
     |}

    res1: String = this is the truth
```

note on above pattern matching: notice the reference equality test with `eq`

Comment: Okay, so the magic appears to be the => in the expression _inverse: =>Relationship. My reading of this is that you are saying that _inverse is no longer an instance of Relationship but a function which returns an instance of Relationship. But when you provide the _inverse argument you are just passing in a reference (or is it a lazy reference).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Lovely green tick and +1 for you.